# how to get specific pattern of sub string from string c#?

Tags: string, substring, string-matching, string-math

how to get specific pattern of sub string from string in c# code?

input string like this => "number": 123,"object":"a": "b", "d","e": "f"2233"""""king"

sub strings in string array as =>
"number"
"object"
"a"
"b"
"d"
"e"
"f"
"king"

Answer (score 0):

string substring= Regex.Replace(inpustring, "(\"[0-9]+[\"]{5}|: \"[0-9]+\",)|[:,]", " ");